# Friendly and welcoming, who are we?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Another riddle on the theme of literature.

> Our first has his hands on the money;
>
> Our second has his hands in fire;
>
> Our third was an outcast for years.
>
> Our fourth and fifth were together:
> One dead, one deaf, or nearly so.
>
> Our sixth was tall and most important,
>
> Our seventh was different from all the rest.
>
> Friendly and welcoming, who are we?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's:

> The weasley kids from the Harry Potter Books.

```
Our first has his hands on the money;
```

> Bill the eldest, works for the wizard bank Gringotts as a treasure hunter.

```
Our second has his hands in fire;
```

> Charlie the 2nd, works with dragons.

```
Our third was an outcast for years.
```

> Percy is a prick and was kind of alienated from the rest of the family until the very end of the series.

```
Our fourth and fifth were together:
One dead, one deaf, or nearly so.
```

> The twins, Fred and George, one got his ear chopped off, the other killed.

```
Our sixth was tall and most important,
```

> Ron, one of the main characters, also supposed to be tall.

```
Our seventh was different from all the rest.
```

> Ginny, the only girl.

```
Friendly and welcoming, who are we?
```

> The Weasley kids.

Comment: Well done! The "who are we" was meant to be the parents, but I suppose it's ambiguous. It was you who inspired me to write this riddle, btw :-)

Comment: Yeah I found it that fast because of the '7'. I basically just thought back to all the other books I tried to fit for your other riddle.